# Define a piecewise function in Scilab given the variable as a vector

Tags: scilab

Hi I have the following code in Scilab:

```
>Tc=0;     
>Tm=1;   
>Tf=1800;  
>t=(Tc:1:Tf)';
```

where t is a vector of 1800 components.

And I am asked to do a piecewise function that satisfies certain conditions,

My first try was to do something on the line of

```
> function vg=simula_vg(t,Tcg,Tfg,Ag)   
 >   if (t<Tcg | t>Tfg) then    
  >      vg=0;   
   > else      
    >    vg=Ag*Ag*(1-cos(2*%pi*(t-Tcg)/(Tfg-Tcg)));   
    >end   
>endfunction
```

But it doesnt work as I am asking it to compare vector and scalars.

Then I tried to write this

```
>for i=[Tc:1:Tf]
>function vg=simula_vg(t,Tcg,Tfg,Ag)   
   > vg(t<Tcg)=0    
    >vg(t>Tfg)=0    
    >vg((Tcg<=t)&(t<=Tfg))=sin(t(i))    
>endfunction    
>end
```

But I doesnt work either and I have run out of ideas, is there anything else I can do? All the variables are well defined

```
>vm=10;   
>Ag=2;    
>Tcg=200;    
>Tfg=400;    
>Ar=2;   
>Tcr=1000;   
>Tfr=1500;    
>As=2;    
>fs=0.0008;    
>h=20;     
>d=0.6;
```

There are more because there are more functions similar to that one that I have to define and I dont know how. Any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, where the zero values are defined afterwards:

```
function vg=simula_vg(t,Tcg,Tfg,Ag)    
  vg=Ag*Ag*(1-cos(2*%pi*(t-Tcg)/(Tfg-Tcg)));   
  vg(t<Tcg|t>Tfg)=0;   
endfunction

Ag=2;    
Tcg=200;    
Tfg=400;
Tc=0;     
Tm=1;   
Tf=1800;  
t=Tc:1:Tf;

vg = simula_vg(t,Tcg,Tfg,Ag);
plot(t,vg)
```

[image]